# Gvim font loading issue

Tags: vim, fonts, gvim

*Possibly related:* [Gvim displays wrong font when set from _gvimrc, but correct font when set from menus](https://superuser.com/questions/101815/gvim-displays-wrong-font-when-set-from-gvimrc-but-correct-font-when-set-from-m?rq=1)

I'm experimenting a weird behavior with *gvim* (under GNU/Linux) while trying to set up a specific font named [lekton](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/lekton). As many options are in the `.vimrc`, my `.gvimrc` file is very simple and it always worked:

```
color kate
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 9
```

Very effective:

[image: Using source code pro]

I can set the *lekton* font easily by using the appropriate command:

[image: lekton works fine]

While if I change the `.gvimrc` with `set guifont=Lekton\ 9` I get the following result:

[image: yuk]

My guess is this has something to do with initialization (maybe something good happens between the reading of `.gvimrc` and the GUI startup?). The weird fact is that both *Source Code Pro* and *Lekton* are *ttf* fonts (so I would expect them to behave in the same way).

Any hint?

Comment: It looks a lot like a corrupt font.

Comment: @romainl, if it was a corrupt font it should not work even if I load it after the program bootstrap... so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: For reference, FontForge reports a number of issues with it and Mac OS X's Font Book refuses to install it.